# Giving null values a label in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have `SQL` statement as follows:

```
Select TableB.section 
from TableA left join TableB on TableA.fk = TableB.pk 
group by TableB.section
```

Since this is `left join`, there is a chance that `TableB.Section` can return a *null* because a row of `TableA.fk` could be *null* and so the group by clause will return *null* for that row.

So there is a chance in which I will get something like this:

```
TableB.Section
-------------
| Section 1 |
+-----------+
| Section 2 |
+-----------+
| NULL      |
+-----------+
```

How can I replace the word `NULL` to a nice text that like: "No value", within my SQL statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *oracle* use `NVL()` as:

```
Select NVL(TableB.section, 'nice text')
from TableA left join TableB on TableA.fk = TableB.pk 
group by NVL(TableB.section, 'nice text')
```

For *SQL Server* you can use `ISNULL(TableB.section, 'nice text')` or `COALESCE(TableB.section, 'nice text')`

I suppose there is also `IFNULL()` in *MySql*.

Edit: As [OracleUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149900/giving-null-values-a-label-in-sql/22150141#22150141)'s answer states; Oracle requires `NVL()` in `group by` as well.

Answer (score 6):

You need to Apply `NVL()`/`COALESCE()` in `GROUP BY` Clause as well!
 Else it would be a Syntax Error itself

```
Select NVL(TableB.section, 'No Value')
from TableA left join TableB on TableA.fk = TableB.pk 
group by NVL(TableB.section, 'No Value')
```

Comment: No idea in oracle (can't test now) but it works just fine without `ISNULL` in `group` in `SQL Server`

Comment: `Oracle` expects it in `GROUP BY` Clause too!

Answer (score 5):

```
Select NVL(TableB.section, 'No Value')
from TableA left join TableB on TableA.fk = TableB.pk 
group by TableB.section
```